# Call Javascript function with Object AND array parameters

Tags: javascript

I've seen many posts about using Javascripts `apply()` and ES6 ellipses calls but they only seem to deal with passing arrays and that's it.
I'd like to pass an Object and an array.

```
function myFunction(obj, arr) {
    // Not really doing this but you get the idea
    if (arr.includes(obj)) {
        ;;
    }
}

let theArr = ["bob", "mike", "steve"];
let o = "sally";

myFunction(o, theArr); // How can I do something equivalent to this?
```

Thanks.

Comment: Based on the logic you have, there is no need to use apply or the spread operator. What exact use of them do you have in mind?

Comment: "sally" is not an object. It is a primitive (string).

Comment: okay.  Doesn't affect the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `apply()` is the *array of arguments*, if you want to pass one object and an array you just have to include those in the array. For example:

```js
function test(el1, el2){
  alert(el1.a);
  alert(el2);
  alert(this.b);
}

test.apply(
    {b: 4}, //First argument, the new *this* variable
    [{a:1}, [2, 3]] //Second argument is the list of arguments passed to test()
);
```